# readxl() converts dates to a number

Tags: r, date, readxl

I have an **xlsx** file like this, with date in the first row:

| jan/20 | mar/2020 | jun/2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | K | L |
| C | Y | B |

For some reason, when importing to R using `readxl()` function, the dates in the header are converted to a number, like:
15890, 17890, etc.

I know that isn't good practice keeping dates as variables, but even transposing the table the problem remains.
I appreciate if someone can help :)

Comment: Can you try `.name_repair = "minimal"` assuming you are using `read_excel`

Comment: it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are reading/writing the data but I cannot reproduce this if I use this data :

```
df <- structure(list(`jan/20` = c("A", "C"), `mar/2020` = c("K", "Y"),
`jun/2020` = c("L", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df

#  jan/20 mar/2020 jun/2020
#1      A        K        L
#2      C        Y        B

#Write the data
writexl::write_xlsx(df, 'test.xlsx')
#Read the data
readxl::read_excel('test.xlsx')

# A tibble: 2 x 3                                                 
# `jan/20` `mar/2020` `jun/2020`
#  <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     
#1 A        K          L         
#2 C        Y          B
```

---

You could change the numeric dates to format of your choice :

```
names(df) <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(names(df)), 
                    origin = '1970-01-01'), '%b/%Y')
df
```